# how to get different images from database by calling a single servlet in while(rs.next())

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, session, servlets

I am trying to get all images from oracle sql database, but it shows a single image every time.
I am using session variables to transfer uuid of the row.

**A simplified Example :**

**JSP Code :**

```
HttpSession ses2=request.getSession();
Connection cn3;
PreparedStatement ps3;
try
{
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
cn3=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:sm","system","gecbsp");
ps3=cn3.prepareStatement("select * from sm_post order by time DESC");
ResultSet rs5=ps3.executeQuery();
while(rs5.next())
{
String puid = rs5.getString("post_uuid");
ses2.setAttribute("ses_puid",puid);
out.println("<img src = './post_pic' width = '400px' height = '300px' border = '2' align = 'middle' name = '"+puid+"'/>");
}
}
catch(Exception ee)
{
ee.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Image Servlet :**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

public class post_pic extends HttpServlet{

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {




        HttpSession ses2=request.getSession();
        String puid = (String)ses2.getAttribute("ses_puid");
        String imgLen="";
        Connection cn;
        PreparedStatement ps;
        try
        {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            cn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:sm","system","gecbsp");
            ps=cn.prepareStatement("select post_image from sm_post where post_uuid = ?");
            ps.setString(1,puid);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            if(rs.next()){
                  imgLen = rs.getString(1);
                  System.out.println(imgLen.length());
                  }  
            ps=cn.prepareStatement("select post_image from sm_post where post_uuid = ?");
            ps.setString(1,puid);
            ResultSet rs2 = ps.executeQuery();
            if(rs2.next()){
                  int len = imgLen.length();
                  byte [] rb = new byte[len];
                  InputStream readImg = rs2.getBinaryStream(1);
                  int index=readImg.read(rb, 0, len);
                  System.out.println("index"+index);
                  ps.close();
                  cn.close();
                  response.reset();
                  response.setContentType("image/jpg");
                  response.getOutputStream().write(rb,0,len);
                  response.getOutputStream().flush();
                  }
                  }
                  catch (Exception e){
                  e.printStackTrace();
                  }
                  ses2.setAttribute("ses_puid", puid);

            }

    }
```

I have 5 pics in my database, but in each img src tag it shows the latest pic inserted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You override session attribute inside the loop:

```
ses2.setAttribute("ses_puid",puid);
```

Try to use request param instead of session attribute:

**JSP:**

```
out.println("<img src = './post_pic?puid="+puid+"' width = '400px' height = '300px' border = '2' align = 'middle' name = '"+puid+"'/>");
```

**Servlet:**

```
String puid = request.getParameter("puid");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/4245401/itpr perfect answer, it works..., thanx a lot..

Comment: but it does not works in <img src>, works in <input type = 'image'>

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> images = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (rs5.next()) {
        String puid = rs5.getString("post_uuid");
        images.add(puid);
    }
ses2.setAttribute("ses_puid", images);
```

And use list of images in JSP